# Trouble with nested ifelse in NetLogo

Tags: if-statement, netlogo

I´m new to NetLogo. Quite new to programming in general too. I read a lot of helpful things here. Now i hit rock bottom with my knowledge and decided to ask my first question ever. No matter how stupid i might sound:

I try to make some turtles move and avoid certain patches in NetLogo. I Tryed to archive this with the following nested ifelse:

```
loop [
ifelse any? Movers with [steps > 0]
[     
 ask Movers with [steps > 0]
[
   ifelse patch-ahead 1 is-Patch? [
     ifelse not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 [
       ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 != white [
         ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 != brown [
fd 1 set steps steps - 1][turnTurtle]
]
       [turnTurtle]
]
     [turnTurtle]
]
   [turnTurtle]
]
]
[stop]
]
```

The loop should run until every Mover has moved once. Thats what I keep track of using the "steps" variable. If any condition is false it will call a procedure called "turnTurtle". The turned turtles will try to move during the next run of the loop or turn again.

I get an "Expected keyword" error when i try to run the code. Why?

ProQuestion: Is there a better way to check patches and turn turtles? This very nested setup might be a poor choice?

Comment: as a tiny aside, I would replace `[ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 != white
  and [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 != brown` with `[pcolor != white and pcolor != brown] of patch-ahead 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get an "Expected keyword" error when i try to run the code. Why?

I don't get that error from the code snippet you posted. (In general you should try to post simplified but "complete" examples of your code that someone can paste into NetLogo and play with. Very often, just trying to create such an example will help you solve your problem.)

What I do get is the "Expected a constant" compilation error because `patch-ahead 1 is-Patch?` is inverted. It should be:

```
is-patch? patch-ahead 1
```

Maybe that was the source of your problem?

> Is there a better way to check patches and turn turtles? This very nested setup might be a poor choice?

As you have correctly seen, deeply nested code is undesirable and can usually be avoided. In your case, that could be achieved by combining your conditions in a single expression using [`and`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#and):

```
ifelse is-patch? patch-ahead 1
  and not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1
  and [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 != white
  and [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 != brown
[
  fd 1
  set steps steps - 1
] [ turnTurtle ]
```

Some more remarks:

Instead of checking for `!= white` and `!= brown` in two separate expressions, you can combine them using [`member?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#member):

```
[ not member? pcolor [ white brown ] ] of patch-ahead 1
```

Instead of combining [`loop`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#loop) with an `if` expression and a `stop` command, you could just use [`while`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#while):

```
while [ any? movers with [ steps > 0 ] ] [     
  ask movers with [ steps > 0 ] [
    ; rest of your code here
  ]
]
```

Finally, I don't think you need it here, but for complicated control flow code, you can use the [`cf` extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/cf.html) that adds "switch" like statements to NetLogo.

Comment: Your advice helped me a lot. Thanks! But i ran into a new problem. I put a complete simplyfied version over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898646/netlogo-model-gets-stuck-w-no-error-mesage)